# Add a timestamp to data simulator

Tags: python, datetime

I am simulating time series data using [Python TestData](https://github.com/arieb/python-testdata) and trying to add a new key value (event_time) that includes a time stamp when the record is generated. The issue is that the field is not incrementing as the script runs, just at first execution. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
import testdata
import datetime


EVENT_TYPES = ["USER_DISCONNECT", "USER_CONNECTED", "USER_LOGIN", "USER_LOGOUT"]
class EventsFactory(testdata.DictFactory):
    event_time = testdata.DateIntervalFactory(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.timedelta(minutes=0))
    start_time = testdata.DateIntervalFactory(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.timedelta(minutes=12))
    end_time = testdata.RelativeToDatetimeField("start_time", datetime.timedelta(minutes=20))
    event_code = testdata.RandomSelection(EVENT_TYPES)

for event in EventsFactory().generate(100):
    print event
```

Outputs:

```
{'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 17, 47, 50, 422020), 'event_code': 'USER_CONNECTED', 'event_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 17, 47, 50, 422006), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 18, 7, 50, 422020)}
{'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 17, 59, 50, 422020), 'event_code': 'USER_CONNECTED', 'event_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 17, 47, 50, 422006), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 18, 19, 50, 422020)}
{'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 18, 11, 50, 422020), 'event_code': 'USER_LOGOUT', 'event_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 17, 47, 50, 422006), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 18, 31, 50, 422020)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for event in EventsFactory().generate(10):
event["event_time"] = datetime.datetime.now()
print event
```

Answer (score 1):

So the [`timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) is how much into the future you want the event to happen. Notice that the `timedelta(minutes=12)` causes the time between each `start_time` generated to be 12 minutes from `datetime.datetime.now()` from the previous iteration of the for-loop (**not the execution of the script**). Similarly, the `end_time` is a relative `timedelta(minutes=20)` to `start_time` so it will always be 20 minutes in front of `start_time`. Your `event_time` is not incrementing because it has no delta (change) value for any time the code is run, and it will always use the `datetime.datetime.now()` from the time the script is run.

It if is test data, I think you would be looking for something like

```
import testdata
import datetime


    EVENT_TYPES = ["USER_DISCONNECT", "USER_CONNECTED", "USER_LOGIN", "USER_LOGOUT"]
    class EventsFactory(testdata.DictFactory):
        start_time = testdata.DateIntervalFactory(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.timedelta(minutes=12))
        event_time = testdata.RelativeToDatetimeField("start_time", datetime.timedelta(minutes=10))
        end_time = testdata.RelativeToDatetimeField("start_time", datetime.timedelta(minutes=20))
        event_code = testdata.RandomSelection(EVENT_TYPES)

    for event in EventsFactory().generate(100):
        print event
```

**Edit**: if it doesn't have to do with the data provided:

So the `testdata.DictFactory` that you are passing in just creates a dictionary based on the instance variables you create as far as I can see.

You want an `event_time` instance variable that gets the time for every iteration of the for-loop, to do that it would look like:

```
import testdata
import datetime


    EVENT_TYPES = ["USER_DISCONNECT", "USER_CONNECTED", "USER_LOGIN", "USER_LOGOUT"]
    class EventsFactory(testdata.DictFactory):
        start_time = testdata.DateIntervalFactory(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.timedelta(minutes=12))
        end_time = testdata.RelativeToDatetimeField("start_time", datetime.timedelta(minutes=20))
        event_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        event_code = testdata.RandomSelection(EVENT_TYPES)

    for event in EventsFactory().generate(100):
        print event
```

If I am understanding what you are wanting correctly, this should achieve it in the output.

**Edit 2**:

After looking at this again this may not achieve what you are wanting because `EventsFactory().generate(100)` seems to instantiate all 100 at the same time, and to get a dictionary key of `event_time` you would **have** to use the `testdata.RelativeToDatetimeField()` method to change the time

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Cole. What I am really trying to accomplish is that each record will have a current (now) timestamp when it is generated by the script during runtime rather that at initial execution. Even with the time delta, it does not increment the time stamp. I suspect it would need to happen in the for loop vs. class def but not sure.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand. Then the data you are looking for isn't a part of the `testdata` class. I edited my response to adapt to what I believe you want.

Comment: I tried this approach as well but the "event_time" is not in the output.